# Why is digital signature enforcement on webservers not common practice?

Tags: certificates, webserver, digital-signature, apache, code-execution

Why is it that server admins do not code sign the contents of their webservers (all  php, css, js, etc.) and have Apache / NGINX / whatever server software refuse to execute or serve any code / content unless it has been digitally signed by a certificate held only by the website administrators?

Exceptions could be made for user uploaded content like photos, and `exec` and `shell_exec` could be made to enforce digital signature verification for any "images" / code they execute.

Why is this not common practice? It certainly wouldn't stop all attacks - SQL injection and XSS would be essentially unaffected, but it could immediately stop almost all remote code execution attacks and website defacing. Is there some downside I am missing? It seems so simple and effective.

Comment: What mechanisms exist to enforce this?

Comment: Most attacks that would let an attacker replace/modify the files in question would also let them reconfigure the server to disable the protection.